# Core Data Migration - Added entity

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data

I have created a new version of my model and set that as my current model. I have added two new entities one of which is dependant on a parent entity.

I have added the following code when setting up my store

```
 NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:  
                         [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption,  
                         [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption, nil];
```

And I have created a mapping model - source my old model and destination my new model. 
However the application still crashes on launch.  I think I'm missing something here. I've tried going through apple docs but still can't quite get what.

Comment: What is the console output of the crash? Just as a sidenote setting NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption as YES means you do not intend to use a mapping model. If you want to use a mapping model you need to set it NO.

Comment: Hi, well I set it to no, not sure if I need to do anything else beyond that. I set an exception breakpoint and I get this:

#0  0x02a7fcf0 in objc_exception_throw ()
#1  0x01926ab7 in +[NSEntityDescription entityForName:inManagedObjectContext:] (

Comment: Does console output show anything? It should.

Comment: No, just a sigabrt if I remove the exception breakpoint. The only log I get is what I posted when I bt in the console.

Comment: Can you repost the console output to your original question please. As much as there is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you give an update with revised core data structure, you will need to update your old data structure with new one. Since old one is already present your .mod files and others are not recreated, so even though your code is having new entities, your application installed in user's device contains old data structure and when you fire a query for those entities in new data structure, app cant find that. So it crashes eventually.

So else you can delete your application which is only for testing purpose. 
If u are creating new version of your app, then please refer [this link](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/38070-how-do-you-update-users-core-data-database-upon-app-update.html)